# Copying Specific Text from Word document to Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a similar problem that another user had. The problem was solved by Xidgel. The code worked for them but does not seem to work for me. I would like to search a word document for anything that has

3 Letters, 'x', 4 Numbers. 
eg. ADZx4391

and copy it in an excel sheet.

```
Sub CopyTPNumber()

    'Create variables
    Dim Word As New Word.Application
    Dim WordDoc As New Word.Document
    Dim r As Word.Range
    Dim Doc_Path As String
    Dim WB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim WB_Name As String


    Doc_Path = "Libraries\Documents\EXPORTCOMMENTS.docx"
    Set WordDoc = Word.Documents.Open(Doc_Path)
    ' Set WordDoc = ActiveDocument

    ' Create a range to search.
    Set r = WordDoc.Content

    'Find text and copy it
    With r
        .Find.ClearFormatting
        With .Find

        With .Find
            .Text = "[A-Z]{3}x[0-9]{4}"
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Execute
   End With
        .Copy
    End With


    'Open excel workbook and paste
    WB_Name = Excel.Application.GetOpenFilename(",*.xlsx")
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(WB_Name)

    WB.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("AB2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    WordDoc.Close
    Word.Quit

End Sub
```

When I run the code, I get user-defined type not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you haven't added reference to Word library?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a reference to Word.

From the VBA Window:

Tools > References > Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library (check the box) > OK

(Note that the number may not be 14.0, depending on your version of Word)

You also have a syntax error (.Find duplicated)